# Probability on algebra and team formation.

Tags: probability

I am having trouble regarding the following problems :

> A team consisting of at least $ 1 $ male student out of $ 5 $ , at least $1$ female out of $ 3 $ and at least $ 1 $ teacher out of $ 2 $ is to be formed. Find the probability that the team contains at least $4$ male students,  at best $2$ female students and $2$ teachers .

-If $x+y=n$ , then what is the probability  of $xy\ge \frac{4}{3}n^2$ ?

**N. B.**  I have confronted algebraic probabilities with circles only... So I am having trouble to set up the second problem...

For the first,  I say :
$$P ( M )  = \frac{1}{5}$$
$$P ( F)   = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$P ( T )  = \frac{1}{2}$$

So the cases are :
$ MMMMFTT,  MMMMFFTT, MMMMMFTT , MMMMMFFTT$ ...
So , I get :
$$P=\frac{1}{5^4}\times\frac{1}{3^2}\times \frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{5^4}\times \frac{1}{3^2}\times \frac{1}{2^2}+ \frac{1}{5^5}\times \frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{5^5}\times \frac{1}{3^2}\times \frac{1}{2^2} $$
 But,  I know I am wrong.  What to do?

Comment: The  answer to the second question is zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first requirement, we get:

1. At least one male student, so $2^5 - 1 = 31$ possibilities;
2. At least one female student, so $2^3 - 1 = 7$ possibilities;
3. At least one teacher, so $2^2 - 1 = 3$ possibilities.

We thus find $31 \cdot 7 \cdot 3 = 651$ possible teams. As for the second requirement, we get:

1. At least four male students, so ${5 \choose 4} + {5 \choose 5} = 6$ possibilities;
2. At most two female students, so ${3 \choose 1} + {3 \choose 2} = 6$ possibilities;
3. Exactly two teachers, so ${2 \choose 2} = 1$ possibility.

We thus find $6 \cdot 6 \cdot 1 = 36$ valid teams. As such, the probability equals:

$$\frac{36}{651} \approx 0.0553$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(x+y)^2 = n^2$$

$$(x+y)^2 = x^2+y^2 +2xy = n^2$$

$$x^2+y^2 = n^2-2xy$$

For the least value of xy which is equal to $\frac{4n^2}{3}$

$$x^2+y^2 = n^2-\frac{8n^2}{3} \lt 0$$

But $x^2+y^2 \ge 0$ and hence the probability that $P(xy\gt \frac{4n^2}{3}) = 0$

Comment: OK...  Got it...

Comment: Would you please tell me how to do it when $x+y=2n$  .... ?